# Is there any practical purpose to breaking stuff?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any benefits to blowing everything up?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66632/are-there-any-benefits-to-blowing-everything-up)

I'm exploring the Cathedral, and occasionally I'll swing and miss at an enemy and bust the fragile stone railings along the edge of certain walkways.

Does breaking these railings do anything?  Some objects do damage, like dropping chandeliers or breaking the supports for sections of the wall, and some objects drop gold or other small loot items, but these type of objects do neither.

Comment: Can this be generalized to breaking "things", (aside from the loot some things drop...)?  Lots of set pieces (wagons, carts, chairs, tables) are in the same bin as railings.

Comment: This should probably be merged with http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66632/are-there-any-benefits-to-blowing-everything-up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beyond the Destruction bonus, they provide a way for a Barbarian to preserve and build Fury.  The other classes with resource-generating attacks—Monk and Demon Hunter—gain no benefit from raging out like this as their pools either do nothing (Monk) or slowly recharge anyways (Demon Hunter).

Comment: Hmm. I thought all classes could use their XYZ building skills on 'Nothing' via shift click or the like to raise their pools.. including the barbarian.

Comment: Actually I think the Demon Hunger gets a boost from shooting at air (though given the base recharge it's somewhat daft), but not the Monk.  In any event, that benefit isn't tied to breaking things.

Answer (score 1):

Stone railings, much like other destructible objects, have little else to do other than show off the physics engine and contribute towards a "Destruction" experience bonus.

Answer (score 1):

They count as destroying something for the destruction bonuses, same as tables, piles of books, barrels and the like.

Just something to add to the chains :)

Answer (score 0):

I always break everything I see.  I have found some of my best equipment from doing that in diablo 2 (like set pieces and what not).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Nick T's [excellent point about preserving fury](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/67060/21619).  Destroying 50 Tombstones counts towards the **Grave Buster** [achievement](http://www.ign.com/wikis/diablo-3/Achievements).  There will probably be more achievements is future expansions, so there may be more like this one in the future.