# Does destroying everything give experience?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any benefits to blowing everything up?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66632/are-there-any-benefits-to-blowing-everything-up)

Do wrecking everything in the enemy base give any amount of exp. aside the bonus you get when you smash more than 6 items in a short time?

Or did I just destroyed every barrel in every dungeon... for NOTHING?

...Well at least I must be the king of barrel destroyers. You never know when the barrels might revolt.

Comment: Does your experience bar show accumulation of xp when you destroy barrels?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only experience bonus for destroying the scenery is the destruction bonus for blowing several up in a short period of time, yes. However, barrels and urns and the like often have small piles of gold, and in later difficulties they're a good source for Pages and Tomes of Blacksmithing and Jewelcrafting, and even Tomes of Secrets on Inferno.

Though you have to wonder whose idea it was to hide nine hundred gold and a Tome of Secrets inside a rotting log.

Answer (score 0):

The only XP benefit you get is when you destroy enough to cause a Destruction spree.  Other than that, you obviously get any gold or other drops from inside them.